# Exclude a class from all of the selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

First of all sorry for my bad English.
I want to exclude a class from all of the selectors in CSS.

I need to use something like

```
(h1, h2, h3, h4, ..., p, span, a, ...):not(.exclude){
   font-family: arial;
}
```

instead of:

```
h1:not(.exclude), h2:not(.exclude), ..., a:not(.exclude){
   font-family: arial;
}
```

Comment: Just set a specific rule for `.exclude` elements that's overriding default rule applied to all elements

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use :not(.exclude) just by itself? Do you have any specific .exclude elements that you want to, ahem, exclude from this rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with CSS4 [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) selector. You can watch out for the browser support here: https://caniuse.com/?search=is but in modern web developer terms, you are safe to use it.

```css
:is(h1,h2,h3):not(.exclude) {
  background: #bada55;
  color: #565656;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="exclude">
  Excluded
</h1>
<h2 class="include">
  Included
</h2>
<h3 class="exclude">
  Excluded
</h3>
```

The above code works like this

```
h1:not(.exclude), h2:not(.exclude), h3:not(.exclude) { Properties... }
```

You can also make use of [`:where`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) which does the same:

```css
:where(h1,h2,h3):not(.exclude) {
  background: #bada55;
  color: #565656;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="exclude">
  Excluded
</h1>
<h2 class="include">
  Included
</h2>
<h3 class="exclude">
  Excluded
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*:not(.exclude) {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

would give everything font family arial except elements with class .exclude, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Listing all of the element types they want to apply :not(.exclude) to seems to suggest that there are element types they don't want this negation to apply to. It seems like it'd be easier for them to add a second :not() that excludes just that selection of element types, rather than listing out all the ones they do want it to apply to. However if they just want to apply this negation to all elements, then this answer is the way to go.